# Can you still update extension via Magento Downloader?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-connect

In mid September magento has switched to magento Marketplace and shut down Magento Commerce website. I have several extensions that I originally installed via Magento Commerce key and they show the update is available for them when I check in the Magento Downloader

**Can I update these extensions via Magento Downloader?** My only concern is that Magento Commerce website is no longer available I am not sure how the update will go.

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing and YES, we can update already installed extensions via Magento Connect Manager. But keep in mind that available version showing in Magento Connects are the ones that the respective extension developers have published before Mid september of 2017 (aka before the magento closed down MagentoCommerce.com website.